# What does "disti 5 pack" mean in the context of Intel's server boards?

Tags: intel, hardware

I've just ordered a [motherboard](http://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B008C12C5A) for a new server I'm building.

It's description says "INTEL DBS2600CP4 BOARD S2600CP4 DISTI 5 PACK BOARD".

However, since I had previous issues with Amazon's descriptions of technological items, I'd like to know what does "Disti 5 Pack" means in the context of motherboards.
Given my previous experiences (bought a professional server and received just its chassis), I'm afraid of nasty surprises.

However my google-fu wasn't able to find an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is part of a 5 pack of boards sold to distributors or system builders.  They then sell the boards one at a time or build custom systems.

Comment: Thanks @DaveM. Now I'm afraid of what they could send (or rather not send) me.

Comment: @GiacomoTesio That looks like the right price for a single board (including VAT) so the seller probably bought a 5 pack and then sold them individually on Amazon.

Comment: @GiacomoTesio  As Michael Hampton says, no need for concern.  Looks like a legitimate deal and seller has simply copied the full "name" from whatever source they bought from